# left join with both aggregate function and select on joining table

Tags: sql, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, left-join

I have a general SQL query question that I think could be answered in various SQL flavors, although my example below is using spark sql.

I am trying to left join table 1 (`t1`) onto table 2 (`t2`), with the following goals:

1. Keep all the values in `t1` (hence left join)
2. select a column in `t2` based on an aggregate function in `t2`

Here are some test data:

```
t1
+---+--------+
|pk1|constant|
+---+--------+
|  a|constant|
|  b|constant|
|  c|constant|
|  d|constant|
+---+--------+
```

```
t2
+---+---------+------+
|fk1|condition|target|
+---+---------+------+
|  a|        1|check1|
|  a|        2|check2|
|  b|        1|check1|
|  b|        2|check2|
+---+---------+------+
```

Here are a couple (failed) sample queries:

```scala
spark.sql("""
    select
        pk1,
        constant,
        target
    from
        t1
    left join
        t2
    on
        pk1 = fk1
    group by
        pk1, constant, target
    having
        min(condition)
""").show
+---+--------+------+
|pk1|constant|target|
+---+--------+------+
|  b|constant|check1|
|  a|constant|check2|
|  a|constant|check1|
|  b|constant|check2|
+---+--------+------+
```

**Problem with query 1**: I have lost the `t1` rows for `pk1` in `'c'`,`'d'`. It looks like an inner join to me and not a left join.

```scala
spark.sql("""
    select
        pk1,
        constant,
        min(condition),
        target
    from
        t1
    left join
        t2
    on
        pk1 = fk1
    group by
        pk1, constant, target
""").show
+---+--------+--------------+------+
|pk1|constant|min(condition)|target|
+---+--------+--------------+------+
|  a|constant|             1|check1|
|  a|constant|             2|check2|
|  b|constant|             2|check2|
|  b|constant|             1|check1|
|  c|constant|          null|  null|
|  d|constant|          null|  null|
+---+--------+--------------+------+
```

**Problem with query 2**: I no longer have a filter on the minimum value for condition. For example, for `pk1 = a`, I have taken `condition = 1` and `condition = 2`. The min function was seemingly not applied.

**Desired Output**

```
+---+--------+--------------+------+
|pk1|constant|min(condition)|target|
+---+--------+--------------+------+
|  a|constant|             1|check1|
|  b|constant|             1|check1|
|  c|constant|          null|  null|
|  d|constant|          null|  null|
+---+--------+--------------+------+
```

The `min(condition)` column is optional. I will filter it out later anyways.

I can create the desired output by separating the query into two statements, but I feel like there must be an elegant single-query solution here. Would someone have an idea how to accomplish this? Thank you!

##### appendix

Here are the commands to construct the test tables in case anyone wants to duplicate the test:

```scala
val columns1 = Seq("pk1", "constant")
val columns2 = Seq("fk1","condition","target")
val data1 = Seq( ("a","constant"), ("b","constant"), ("c","constant"), ("d","constant") )
val data2 = Seq( ("a",1,"check1"), ("a",2,"check2"), ("b",1,"check1"), ("b",2,"check2") )
val t1 = spark.createDataFrame(data1).toDF(columns1:_*)
val t2 = spark.createDataFrame(data2).toDF(columns2:_*)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, group by `t2` on `fk1` and use min on `struct(condition, target)` to get the corresponding target value of the min condition then join the grouped result with `t1` :

```scala
spark.sql("""   
  WITH t3 AS (
    SELECT  fk1, 
            MIN(struct(condition, target))['target'] AS target
    FROM    t2
    GROUP BY fk1
  )

  SELECT  pk1,
          constant,
          target
  FROM    t1
  LEFT JOIN t3
  ON    pk1 = fk1
""").show

//+---+--------+------+
//|pk1|constant|target|
//+---+--------+------+
//|  a|constant|check1|
//|  b|constant|check1|
//|  c|constant|  null|
//|  d|constant|  null|
//+---+--------+------+
```

---

Another way by using `row_number()` window function:

```scala
spark.sql("""
    WITH t3 AS (
      SELECT  *, 
              ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY fk1 ORDER BY condition) AS rn
      FROM    t2
    )
    
    SELECT  pk1,
            constant,
            target
    FROM    t1
    LEFT JOIN t3
    ON    pk1 = fk1
    AND   rn = 1
""").show
```

---

And if you want to left join then do the aggregation:

```scala
spark.sql("""   
    SELECT  pk1,
            MAX(constant) AS constant,
            MIN(struct(condition, target))['target'] AS target
    FROM    t1
    LEFT JOIN t2
    ON    pk1 = fk1
    GROUP BY pk1
""").show
```

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with the ``agg(struct())['column name']`` syntax. Do you know if there is a name for this that I can google to read more about? Why is the struct type required?

Comment: @Blaisem take a look at https://keestalkstech.com/2019/11/easy-spark-optimization-for-max-record-aggregate-instead-of-join/